# Added 2 imageview on 3rd imageview now want to convert the 3rd imageviews image into an actual image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am having 3 image views and on one button touch I have added those images to the 3rd image view done something like this

```
-(void) loadView
{
 [super loadView];
 [self.view addSubview:wormimage];
 [self.view addSubview:appleimage];
 [self.view addSubview:finalimage];
 [self.view addSubview:saveButton];
 [self.view addSubview:btn];
 [appleimage addSubview:wormimage];
}
```

and this is the button touch method

```
-(void) addImage
{
 [finalimage addSubview:appleimage];
}
```

Now what I want know is that the 3rd imageview contains 2 image view (appleimage and worm image)
what I don't know is how this can be converted into an entire image itself, what has to be used in order to do that, the final output on the button touch must be an image, extension of the image doesn't matter.

How can I convert the entire view into an image and save them into the gallery of the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

//Draw the View that you wanted

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext
```